# Why does my axios create function in React does not work?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm working on a fullstack app with Express and React. For the calls to the backend, I use axios (version 1.1.2). Before this version, I was using a function to avoid writing the same calls to the database every time. Now, I get this error:

```bash
POST http://localhost:5005/api/auth/signup 400 (Bad Request)
```

Where does it come from?

This is my non working code:

```js
const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: `${API_URL}/api`,
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
})
```

```js
// Here, http refers to the axios.create function
class AuthService {
    signup(data: any) {
        return http.post("/auth/signup", data)
    }
}
```

```js
const handleSubmit = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    authService
        .signup(inputs)
        ...rest
}
```

But this is working:

```js
const handleSubmit = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    axios
        .post(`${API_URL}/api/auth/signup`, inputs)
        ...rest
}
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

When I submit the form, on the front end I get this error, which on the back end would be returned if an input is empty:

```
Please provide your full name.
```

Back end code:

```js
if (!fullName) {
    return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "Please provide your full name." })
}
```

EDIT 2:

I tried to add a `console.log` on the back end with the `req.body` and this is what I get:

```
{}
```

This is the full backend code:

```js
router.post("/signup", (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, fullName, password } = req.body

    console.log(req.body)

    if (!fullName) {
        return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ message: "Please provide your full name." })
    }

    User.findOne({ email })
        .then(foundUser => {
            ...rest

            return User.create({
                email,
                fullName,
                password,
            }).then(createdUser => {
                const payload = { user: createdUser }

                const authToken = jwt.sign(
                    payload,
                    process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
                    jwtConfig
                )

                res.status(201).json({
                    user: createdUser,
                    authToken: authToken,
                })
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

And my terminal returns this:

```
POST /api/auth/login 401 16.919 ms - 39
```

EDIT 3:

This is my Express app.js:

```
require("dotenv/config")
require("./db")
const express = require("express")

const app = express()

require("./config")(app)

const allRoutes = require("./routes/index")
app.use("/api", allRoutes)

require("./error-handling")(app)

module.exports = app
```

You can find the full repo here: https://github.com/JulSeb42/tsx-express-jwt

Comment: Please share the index.js or/and app.js code

Comment: The React one or Express?

Comment: The backend, express

Comment: I edited the post with this page, and added a link to the repo where all my files are

Comment: you need to use  express.json() middleware to get data from req.body

you should include it in ./app.js file. 

check https://expressjs.com/en/api.html for the official doc.

Comment: Can you try to add `app.use(express.json())` to your app.js?

Comment: I'm getting the same error: `POST /api/auth/login 401 5.707 ms - 39`

I tried deleting the `headers` on my axios.create function, like this, and it works:

```
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "/api",
})
```